# How can I fix my Angular 9 websites which are loading infinitely?

Tags: angular, typescript, loading

I have a problem with all Angular 9 projects I am working on. When I attempt to load any of them in the browser locally after running `ng serve` I only get a white page that never stops loading. If I let it run long enough, the browser eventually tells me there is a long running script.

I don't get any errors or warnings in the **angular cli** neither when I compile nor at runtime. The browser also doesn't report any errors.

If I move the projects to a different computer, they work without any issues.

This problem appeared out of the blue when I was working on a project. I've tried deleting every non essential file/folder (like **node_modules**) and re initializing them but that didn't seem to help.

If I pause the script execution, it mostly pauses inside the `_updateTaskCount` function in the `zone-evergreen.js` file. It does pause in other places as well, but 9 out of 10 times it's `_updateTaskCount`.

Another thing I noticed, and I don't know if this is related or expected behavior, but in the network tab  I see that the status of a request for `sockjs.js` is continuously pending.

If I set breakpoints in my code, the only ones that are being hit are the ones from the **ngOnInit** and constructor of the `app.component.ts` file.

I don't know if this is relevant, but here is the callstack when it pauses inside that function:

```
_updateTaskCount (zone-evergreen.js:263)
scheduleTask (zone-evergreen.js:222)
scheduleMicroTask (zone-evergreen.js:230)
scheduleResolveOrReject (zone-evergreen.js:847)
resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:785)
(anonymous) (zone-evergreen.js:705)
(anonymous) (router.js:7275)
unsubscribe (Subscription.js:34)
unsubscribe (Subscription.js:47)
unsubscribe (Subscriber.js:69)
unsubscribe (Subscription.js:47)
unsubscribe (Subscriber.js:69)
unsubscribe (Subscription.js:47)
unsubscribe (Subscriber.js:69)
_innerSub (switchMap.js:41)
_next (switchMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (map.js:35)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (filter.js:33)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
next (Subject.js:39)
next (BehaviorSubject.js:30)
setTransition (router.js:7379)
scheduleNavigation (router.js:7765)
navigateByUrl (router.js:7589)
navigate (router.js:7623)
canActivate (auth-external.guard.ts:16)
(anonymous) (router.js:5556)
(anonymous) (defer.js:8)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (take.js:22)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
_tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
_next (mergeMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
(anonymous) (subscribeToArray.js:3)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (mergeMap.js:21)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_complete (combineLatest.js:52)
complete (Subscriber.js:61)
(anonymous) (subscribeToArray.js:5)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (combineLatest.js:26)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (scan.js:18)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (filter.js:13)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (map.js:16)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (take.js:22)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_innerSub (switchMap.js:46)
_next (switchMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
(anonymous) (subscribeToArray.js:3)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (switchMap.js:17)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
_tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
_next (mergeMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
(anonymous) (subscribeToArray.js:3)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (mergeMap.js:21)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (filter.js:13)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (take.js:22)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (defaultIfEmpty.js:10)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
_tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
_next (mergeMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
(anonymous) (subscribeToArray.js:3)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (mergeMap.js:21)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (filter.js:13)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (take.js:22)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (defaultIfEmpty.js:10)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
_tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
_next (mergeMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_complete (defaultIfEmpty.js:25)
complete (Subscriber.js:61)
_complete (Subscriber.js:79)
complete (Subscriber.js:61)
_complete (Subscriber.js:79)
complete (Subscriber.js:61)
_complete (mergeMap.js:67)
complete (Subscriber.js:61)
(anonymous) (subscribeToArray.js:5)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (mergeMap.js:21)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (filter.js:13)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (take.js:22)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (defaultIfEmpty.js:10)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (mergeMap.js:21)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (map.js:16)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
_tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
_next (mergeMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (map.js:35)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (tap.js:46)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
notifyNext (switchMap.js:70)
_next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (map.js:35)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
(anonymous) (subscribeToArray.js:3)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (map.js:16)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_innerSub (switchMap.js:46)
_next (switchMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
notifyNext (switchMap.js:70)
_next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (tap.js:46)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (tap.js:46)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
notifyNext (mergeMap.js:72)
_next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (map.js:35)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
(anonymous) (subscribeToArray.js:3)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (map.js:16)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
_tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
_next (mergeMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (tap.js:46)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
notifyNext (switchMap.js:70)
_next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (map.js:35)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (Subscriber.js:72)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (map.js:35)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (map.js:35)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (map.js:35)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_next (throwIfEmpty.js:24)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
_complete (takeLast.js:52)
complete (Subscriber.js:61)
_complete (mergeMap.js:67)
complete (Subscriber.js:61)
(anonymous) (subscribeToArray.js:5)
_trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
subscribe (Observable.js:28)
call (mergeMap.js:21)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (takeLast.js:22)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (throwIfEmpty.js:13)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (map.js:16)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (map.js:16)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (map.js:16)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (catchError.js:16)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
call (map.js:16)
subscribe (Observable.js:23)
subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
_innerSub (switchMap.js:46)
_next (switchMap.js:36)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
notifyNext (switchMap.js:70)
_next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
next (Subscriber.js:49)
(anonymous) (subscribeToPromise.js:5)
invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
onInvoke (core.js:41836)
invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
(anonymous) (zone-evergreen.js:857)
invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
onInvokeTask (core.js:41814)
invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask (zone-evergreen.js:552)
scheduleTask (zone-evergreen.js:388)
onScheduleTask (zone-evergreen.js:272)
scheduleTask (zone-evergreen.js:378)
scheduleTask (zone-evergreen.js:210)
scheduleMicroTask (zone-evergreen.js:230)
scheduleResolveOrReject (zone-evergreen.js:847)
resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:785)
(anonymous) (zone-evergreen.js:705)
webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap:25)
(anonymous) (modules-external-view-external-view-module.js:1)
```

I have no idea what to do.

Edit: this is the output after running `ng serve`:

```
16% building 51/52 modules 1 active ...-loader\src\index.js??embedded!node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js??ref--13-3!src\styles.scssDEPRECATION WARNING: As of Dart Sass 2.0.0, !global assignments won't be able to
declare new variables. Since this assignment is at the root of the stylesheet,
the !global flag is unnecessary and can safely be removed.

chunk {common} common.js, common.js.map (common) 3.25 kB  [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 129 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {modules-external-view-external-view-module} modules-external-view-external-view-module.js, modules-external-view-external-view-module.js.map (modules-external-view-external-view-module) 29.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {modules-internal-view-internal-view-module} modules-internal-view-internal-view-module.js, modules-internal-view-internal-view-module.js.map (modules-internal-view-internal-view-module) 49.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 150 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 9.16 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 725 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 6.89 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-07-09T09:29:02.896Z - Hash: c8002f2bc2cc70210c50 - Time: 38856ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: pls post the screen shot of command window after ng serve

Comment: I've added the output of that command.

Comment: it seems like the building is not completed due to some code in the style.css

Comment: It worked just fine before and I moved the entire project folder to a different computer and again it works just fine. Besides, that file is from a module in node_modules folder. I may cause a rupture in the space-time fabric if I manually edit something in there. I also never understood why I need ~700 MB worth of modules for a project that is just a few hundred kilobytes big. I guess these new frameworks are more and more "efficient".

Comment: so, it got works now?right

Comment: nope. I tried opening that file. The only thing I found inside is:`"use strict";

const loader = require('./index');

module.exports = loader.default;`

Comment: can you check your node version, node -v

Comment: @FatehMohamed Sure, it's v13.8.0

Comment: try to delete node_modules folder and then "npm cache clean --force"

Comment: I tried this before I posted the question, tried it again, no difference :(

Comment: If anyone is wondering, my boss eventually gave me a different virtual machine to work on and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

first, check any node modules outdated by using the following command,

```
npm outdated
```

The outdated command will list any packages that are not up to date

is there any outdated then upgrade these by using the command,

```
npm update --save/--save-dev
```